# Perché "lo spaghetto" o "lo gnocco" invece di "gli spaghetti" o "gli gnocchi"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, cooking

Nei ristoranti italiani di Barcellona ho osservato che molti camerieri, quando arrivano con le portate, dicono "lo spaghetto", "lo gnocco", "la tagliatella", ecc invece di "gli spaghetti", "gli gnocchi", "le tagliatelle", ecc. Ho sempre trovato molto curioso questo modo di esprimersi: mi immagino un piatto con un solo spaghetto (magari di quelli lunghissimi).

Le mie domande sono:

- Si tratta di un fenomeno regionale oppure è qualcosa che si dice in tutta l'Italia? In quali regioni d'Italia si usa?
- Qual è il motivo di questo tipo di espressioni? Si usano i nomi al singolare perché sono percepiti come nomi collettivi, in modo simile a come si dice "il riso" per indicare l'insieme di tutti i chicchi che sono in un piatto e non "i risi"?
- Si tratta di un fenomeno recente (un po' come nelle mie lingue si è cominciato a dire "le acque" per riferirsi a parecchie bottiglie di acqua) o piuttosto si dice così  "da sempre"?

Comment: A Roma si usa limitatamente, e suona piuttosto affettato, soprattutto se scritto su un menù, dove fa il paio con l'uso degli articoli (“I primi”, “I dessert”), con i prezzi indicati senza centesimi (“8”) e simili trovate geniali.

Comment: Per parlare di piatti di pasta, i nomi singolari in uso a Roma sono altri: carbonara, (a)matriciana etc., usati oltre che come complementi (“bucatini alla matriciana”) anche come sostantivi di per sé (“Stasera mi mangio una bella carbonara”).

Comment: @DaG: Non l'ho mai visto scritto su un menù, ma l'ho ascoltato molte volte. C'era un romano nella cantina del [Foment Hortenc](http://www.fomenthortenc.cat/web2.0/) (purtroppo, adesso non c'è più), che si trova molto vicino a casa mia, e ricordo avergli sentito dire "lo spaghetto carbonara".

Comment: Curiosamente, però, molta gente che non sa italiano pensa che "spaghetti" sia un singolare e aggiunge una "s" finale per fare il plurale.

Comment: Un po' come per _panini_ e il suo “plurale” _paninis_.

Comment: Al nord, da Venezia a Milano, l’uso informale di “spaghetto” per dire un “piatto di spaghetti” o “gnocco” per dire “un piatto di gnocchi “ è abbastanza diffuso. “*Uno spaghetto al pomodoro e uno gnocco burro e salvia al tavolo 15*”. Pensandoci probabilmente l’uso nasce per comodità dei camerieri che passano gli ordini e per evitare errori. Uno spaghetto (un piatto di spaghetti) 3 spaghetti (tre piatti di spaghetti) etc.

Comment: @user070221Concordo, questo era appunto il senso della mia risposta.

Comment: Ci sono due contesti diversi in cui si usa il singolare: (1) tra camerieri e cuochi per capirsi più velocemente e ridurre gli errori, e (2) per "dare un tono" ai menu quando lo si scrive o espone al cliente: "lo spaghetto allo scoglio" per qualche motivo suona più raffinato di "spaghetti allo scoglio" (come nota @DaG nel primo commento). Non credo che vogliamo aprire un'altra discussione "perché i cuochi parlano così", però fatto sta che si usa. :)

Answer (score 2):

Penso che sia una usanza diffusa in quasi tutta Italia, dipende dal metodo di comunicazione tra chi riceve la comanda e chi la passa alla cucina.

Uno spaghetto, uno gnocco, una tagliatella indicano quindi un piatto e fungono come una sorta di nome collettivo, anche se, come dicevo, è più funzionale alla trasmissione di ordini tra sala e cucina, per minimizzare gli errori e le incomprensioni.

Anche nel momento del servizio di solito il cameriere consegna i piatti dicendo, ad esempio:

> "Ecco uno spaghetto"
>  "L'altro spaghetto per chi è?"

oppure come suggerito da @user070221

> "Uno spaghetto al pomodoro e uno gnocco burro e salvia al tavolo 15"

Tra l'altro lo spaghetto ha anche il significato figurato di paura, spavento.

Comment: Vedendo il dialogo che hai messo nel "blockquote", la prima cosa che mi viene in mente è che si tratti di uno scherzo. Poi leggo attentamente la tua risposta e mi accorgo che non è così.

Comment: Il cameriere nel dialogo per spaghetto intende piatto di spaghetti.

Comment: Non ho mai sentito "spaghetto" usato come "paura". Di che regione si parla?

Comment: [Prendere uno spaghetto](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/spaghetto.shtml). Dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli