# "Finale" oppure "fine" di una parola, di una frase, di un paragrafo?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Rileggendo un mio [commento a una vecchia domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9715/perch%c3%a9-lo-spaghetto-o-lo-gnocco-invece-di-gli-spaghetti-o-gli-gnocchi#comment21596_9715), in cui avevo scritto

> molta gente che non sa italiano pensa che "spaghetti" sia un singolare e aggiunge una "s" al finale per fare il plurale

ho avuto il dubbio se avesse usato il termine "finale" in modo adatto o se invece dovesse dire

> molta gente che non sa italiano pensa che "spaghetti" sia un singolare e aggiunge una "s" alla fine per fare il plurale.

Ho letto quello che spiega il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/finale) sull'uso di "finale" come sostantivo, ma tutti gli esempi che ho trovato fanno riferimento a libri, film, spettacoli, composizioni musicali o al gioco degli scacchi, quindi continuo a non essere sicura se veramente si possa usare per indicare la parte finale di una parola.

Ho anche ricercato "finale di una parola" su Google Libri, ma in tutti gli esempi che ho trovato "finale" è un aggettivo  (per esempio, "la vocale finale di una parola") e non un sostantivo. Ricercando invece "fine di una parola" ne appaiono parecchie occorrenze.

Alla [voce "fine"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fine2) dello stesso dizionario ho trovato l'espressione "fine della parola" (e questo mi fa sospettare che, in effetto, si debba dire "fine di una parola" e non "finale di una parlola"), ma anche "la fine del libro, del verso, della sinfonia".

Ecco dunque la domanda: dovrei dire "la fine di una parola" invece di "il finale di una parola"? Allo stesso modo, dovrei sostituire "al finale" con "alla fine" nel commento che ho riportato all'inizio di questo post? E per "frase" o "paragrafo" al posto di "parola"?

Comment: Senz'altro "la fine" / "alla fine". D'altra parte, perché dire "il finale del film" quando "la fine del film" è più giusto, suona meglio ed è più breve?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Perché "la fine del film" dovrebbe essere più giusto? Anche in catalano e in castigliano esistono due sostantivi ("la fi" ed "el final" in catalano, "el fin" ed "el final" in castigliano) e alcune espressioni si possono costruire con tutti e due e altre soltanto con uno.

Comment: Io non capisco che c'entrino Catalano e Castigliano. Comunque: "finale" deriva da "fine" senza aggiungere alcunché, anzi confondendo a causa della sua valenza aggettivale. Parlare bene significa usare termini adatti semplici e precisi in ogni contesto. "Finale" va benissimo, se si parla di un campionato: sottintende la partita finale e distingue da altri modi in cui esso può finire. Ma "finale del film", come "finale della parola" è un orpello inutile. Ma sentiamo anche altri.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: L'italiano *finale*, il catalano *final* e il castigliano *final* provengono dal latino *finalis*. Invece, l'italiano *fine*, il catalano *fi* e il castigliano *fin* procedono dal latino *fīnis*.

Comment: Non metto in dubbio che "finale di una parola" non si dica in italiano, però. Infatti, se ho posto questa domanda è perché quando ho riletto quel mio commento mi è suonato male, ma non saprei dire perché.

Comment: _Il_ finale e _la_ finale sono due parole diverse. La prima fa parte della terminologia usata nell'analisi musicale, cinematografica e di altre forme di spettacolo, la seconda, come dice giustamente @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, riguarda le fasi conclusive di campionati sportivi e simili. La fine di uno spettacolo è il momento in cui termina e si accendono le luci; il finale è l'ultima parte, che può essere un'intera scena di un'opera, un ultimo movimento di una composizione musicale o le ultime scene di un film.

Comment: Ah, sì, @DaG: anche in castigliano e in catalano esiste "la final" con esattamente lo stesso significato  dell'italiano "la finale". Ed è diverso di "el final". E, a pensarci bene, "el fin de la película" ed "el final de la película" ("la fi de la pel·lícula" ed "el final de la pel·lícula" in catalano) sono diversi: è esattamente la stessa cosa che hai spiegato per l'italiano.

Comment: Tuttavia, in castigliano diciamo "el final de la palabra", "el final de la frase", "el final del párrafo" (in catalano, "el final de la paraula", "el final de la frase", "el final del paràgraf").

Answer (score 2):

Puoi “aggiungere una ‘s’ finale” (aggettivo) o “aggiungere una ‘s’ alla fine” (sostantivo).

*Finale* può essere maschile o femminile. Nel secondo caso si usa nel linguaggio sportivo (partita finale) o in altri casi quando il sostantivo è sottinteso. Qui ci interessa il caso maschile.

Il *finale di un film* è la parte conclusiva, che può anche essere lunga; la fine è il momento finale.

> Il finale di ‘A qualcuno piace caldo’, cioè la fuga in motoscafo, è una delle scene più divertenti della storia del cinema.
>
> Alla fine di ’A qualcuno piace caldo’, Daphne/Jerry si toglie la parrucca e Osgood dice ‘Nessuno è perfetto’.
>
> Non si può aggiungere o togliere nulla al finale di ‘A qualcuno piace caldo’.
>
> Alla fine (della proiezione) di `A qualcuno piace caldo’ ci fu un lungo applauso.

Vero, nella prima frase si può anche dire *la fine*, ma non sarebbe del tutto preciso. Nella seconda frase si può dire *nel finale*. Nella terza frase *alla fine* proprio non ci starebbe.

Quindi *finale* (sostantivo maschile) è ciò che conduce alla fine (di un romanzo, di un film, di una partita).

*La finale* di una parola può essere la sua sillaba finale.

Comment: Grazie, @egreg. E dovrei anche dire *fine di una parola, di una frase, di un paragrafo*, vero? Per esempio: "Si deve mettere un punto alla fine della frase".

Comment: @Charo Sì, certo. È esattamente lo stesso.

Comment: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta, per favore, @egreg?

Comment: Ho corretto quel commento.